# MySQL Partition / Very High Volume of Records

Tags: mysql, partition

I'm looking for some advice on how to setup my MYSQL instance.  I have a table that maintains log entries and I'm getting about 10-11 million entries per month.  I feel like this is far too many records for a single table (~120 million for the year) so I'm seeking advice on a better way to set this up.

I could create a table for every month but that would make my PHP code extremely complicated.  I've never dealt with record sets quite this large before and am looking for any advice you may have.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just logging is there any reason you need to be able to run SQL queries on the data set?  For logging flat files are often a lot easier to work with.  Could you log to flat files, or extract the data periodically from the database?  Or along the same lines, run a SQL script periodically that splits the data into tables by month.  (This will require re-working your query scripts, but not your insert.)

MySQL will handle tables that large, but you are in somewhat uncharted space.  Appending records and keeping the number of indexes to a minimum will help.  MyISAM may be slightly better than some of the alternatives if you can accept its limitations.

You could also run two database instances (preferably on separate servers).  Use replication to stream the log data to the second server and run your queries there.  That will keep the queries on the log table from impacting your production server.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!  The source of the logs is actually flat files which I'm importing into the database.  Having them accessible in the DB is necessary for our DB which allows our web app to manipulate the data.  My thought was to create a table for each month but I don't know how to do that without completely reworking our queries within the web app.  I'm trying to read up on partitioning but have to admit that I don't quite understand it yet.